# How to Customize Domain in Firebase Dynamic Link(FDL)?

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links, url-shortener

I went through Firebase Dynamic Link(FDL) [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) and [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/url-shortener) but could not find any way to use a custom domain.

All I can confirm is we can customize subdomain but not the domain. i.e we can use https://example.page.link/... but not https://example.com/....

Is it possible to have the custom domain? It would work for me if they're providing custom domain support to premium Google API accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an update from Firebase support that they have just released a new update to customize domain in the dynamic link in March 2019. Refer [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains).